# How to use multiple regex patterns using rlike in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have to use multiple patterns to filter a large file. The problem is I am not sure about the efficient way of applying multiple patterns using `rlike`. As an example

```python
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('www 17 north gate',),
        ('aaa 45 north gate',),
        ('bbb 56 west gate',),
        ('ccc 56 south gate',),
        ('Michigan gate',),
        ('Statue of Liberty',),
        ('57 adam street',),
        ('19 west main street',),
        ('street burger',)
    ],
    [ 'poi']
)

df.show()
+-------------------+
|                poi|
+-------------------+
|  www 17 north gate|
|  aaa 45 north gate|
|   bbb 56 west gate|
|  ccc 56 south gate|
|      Michigan gate|
|  Statue of Liberty|
|     57 adam street|
|19 west main street|
|      street burger|
+-------------------+
```

If i use the following two patterns from the data I could do

```python
pat1="(aaa|bbb|ccc) [0-9]+ (north|south|west|east) gate$"
pat2="[0-9]+ [a-z\s]+ street$"
df.filter(~df['poi'].rlike(pat2)).filter(~df['poi'].rlike(pat1)).show()
+-----------------+
|              poi|
+-----------------+
|www 45 north gate|
|    Michigan gate|
|Statue of Liberty|
|    street burger|
+-----------------+
```

how about if I have 40 different patterns? I guess I can use a loop like this

```python
for pat in [pat1,pat2,....,patn]:
    df = df.filter(~df['poi'].rlike(pat))
```

Is this the right approach? The original data is in Chinese so please ignore if the patterns are efficient or not. I am just interested to see how I handle multiple regex patterns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both approaches you suggested have the same execution plan:

Using two patterns in succession:

```python
df.filter(~df['poi'].rlike(pat2)).filter(~df['poi'].rlike(pat1)).explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*Filter (NOT poi#297 RLIKE [0-9]+ [a-z\s]+ street$ && 
#         NOT poi#297 RLIKE (aaa|bbb|ccc) [0-#9]+ (north|south|west|east) gate$)
#+- Scan ExistingRDD[poi#297]
```

Using a loop:

```python
# this is the same as your loop
df_new = reduce(lambda df, pat: df.filter(~df['poi'].rlike(pat)), [pat1, pat2], df)
df_new.explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*Filter (NOT poi#297 RLIKE (aaa|bbb|ccc) [0-9]+ (north|south|west|east) gate$ && 
#         NOT poi#297 RLIKE [0-9]+ [a-z\s]+ street$)
#+- Scan ExistingRDD[poi#297]
```

An alternative approach is to combine all your patterns into one using `"|".join()` to chain them together with the regex `or` operator. The main difference is that this will result in only one call to `rlike` (as opposed to one call per pattern in the other method):

```python
df.filter(~df['poi'].rlike("|".join([pat1, pat2]))).explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*Filter NOT poi#297 RLIKE (aaa|bbb|ccc) [0-9]+ (north|south|west|east) gate$|[0-9]+ [a-#z\s]+ street$
#+- Scan ExistingRDD[poi#297]
```

Comment: In terms of efficiency/running time , joining patterns as  rlike("|".join([pat1, pat2]))) vs doing it in a loop  is better or is about the same?

Comment: I *believe* the joined pattern will be better than the loop because there will only be one call to `rlike`

Comment: I've tried this second method too, but how would you do it so that you would also know which regex pattern matched?

Comment: Might be best to create a new question with a [mcve].